# Start a nix-shell with only the current directory mounted (similar to a container)

Tags: containers, nixos

I am looking for a way to launch a shell with specific packages installed within, but no unnecessary access to the rest of the system, i.e:

- Only the current directory (`pwd`) mounted, no access to other parts of the filesystem*
- Only the requested packages being available*, plus the shell
- Being able to disable network access would be a plus
- Generally no access to other parts of the system*
  So I'm looking for an environment similar to what can be achieved with [`docker`](https://docker.com): (or [`podman`](https://podman.io), etc...)

  ```
  docker run -it -v "$PWD:/pwd" -w /pwd $someImage
  ```

  or Guix:

  ```
  guix shell --pure --container --network $somePackage
  ```

**except strictly necessary ones*

Is this possible with `nix`? The advantage would be that storage for the contents of packages is shared with the host system, familiarity with the system, and so on; and, compared to [`guix`](https://guix.gnu.org), that Nix has a lot more packages available..

Comment: I think you look for something like a jail

Answer (score 0):

containers' underlying technologies are chroots and namespaces which you can use to achieve what you're looking for.

The chroot part which will limit filesystem view is often called a jail (by analogy with BSD), network access can be restricted via namespaces.

However, if you're looking for a copy-pastable solution, I'd highly suggest you stick with containers which will wrap most of it for you.

Comment: This is a question about `nix-shell` specifically.